# aptana studio 3 with python 3.x

Tags: python, macos, aptana

I've been using Aptana Studio 3 on my mac for web development for some time now. I just started learning python 3.3 & tkinter using IDLE but it crashes on me fairly often and I heard Aptana supports python.  When installing PyDev, I only see the option to use python 2.7.  I would prefer to keep using python 3.3 as that's what I have been learning.

Is there a way to use python 3.3 in Aptana?
Are there any other good IDE's?

Comment: What version of PyDev is installed?... I have not used Aptana but in eclipse you can add in a second interpreter. You will have to locate Python 3 on your system. By default on your Mac when you run python what version do you get?

Comment: great thanks! my default is 2.7 but i added the 3.3 interpreter

Comment: no problem!.. just one of those things that don't auto configure :)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which supports any interpreter you've installed.

And ofcourse [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which isn't a complete IDE, but an absolutely fantastic text editor for any purpose.